# How do I establish multiple random numbers in a single Arduino sketch?

Tags: for-loop, random, arduino

I have an Arduino sketch with which I'm planning to control 8 LEDs to blink or fade at different rates. I want to set up a random number from 1-8random for my output pin, a random number from 30-300 for the `delay()` value within the loop, and a third random number for the `+=X` controlling the velocity of the fade in or out. I'd also like to establish a random number that dictates whether the light blinks or fades (a boolean random would work here...).

Here's where I'm fuzzy. From the documentation, I gleaned that the `randomSeed()` function will drive `random(x,y)`, but it seems to infer that ALL the `random(x,y)` values I define will use the same seed within the same sketch.

There did not seem to be a way to define seed A to drive random A and seed B to drive random B. Am I reading that right? I was unable to find any samples that do what I want to do.

Pseudocode below:

```
void setup() {
    pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
#
#  How can I assocaiate pinSeed with pin, delaySeed with delay and velSeed with velocity?
#
    int pinSeed = RandomSeed(analogRead(0));
    int pin = Random1(4,13);
    int delaySeed = RandomSeed(analogRead(0));
    int delay = Random(30,200);
    int velSeed = RandomSeed(analogRead(0);
    int velocity = Random(1,21);
    for (i=0;i=255;+=velocity) {
        analogWrite(pin,i);
        delay(velocity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A seed value sets the starting point for a sequence of random (psuedo-random actually) numbers.  After the seed is set you can draw random numbers, you do NOT to reset or redefine your seed to get a second random number.  Usually a seed is only required to be generated once in a program.

Being able to set the seed allows you to re-create the sequence of random numbers on a second, third, etc. execution of the code.  This helps with debugging!

Also, each random number that is returned can be normalized to a different range of values, as in 1-8 or 30-300, and a boolean can be defined as < 5 (false) or >= 5 (true) when the random number is normalized to 1 thru 10 (for example).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I thkink I get what you're saying: setting the seed once PER EXECUTION will still allow me to select multiple DIFFERENT random numbers without re-seeding. A second execution of the same code will result in the same multiple DIFFERENT random numbers. Seeding occurs once per EXECUTION, not once per generation of a random number. Is that basically what you just said? :)

Comment: @dwwilson66, yes, that is exactly what i meant.  will edit for clarity.